# Django - How to set the request in the admin form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a form that uses the request object:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('title', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In my views, whenever I want to instantiate the form, it is as easy as doing the following:

```
class FooCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Foo
    form_class = FooForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(FooCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'request': self.request})
        return kwargs
```

Now, I want to use the same form in the admin panel, so I do the following:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FooForm
```

But Boom! It dies:

```
KeyError at /admin/foo/foo/add/
'request'
```

I tried to do the following, but it didn't work

```
def get_form(self, request, *args,  **kwargs):
    form = super(FooAdmin, self).get_form(request, *args, **kwargs)
    form.request = request
    kwargs['request'] = request
    return form
```

In summary, is there a way to pass the request to the admin form?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `get_form()` method only returns the class, not an instance of it. The instantiation of the form is hidden in the `add_view` and `change_view` methods of the `ModelAdmin`.
You can somehow work your way around that with creating a new form class in the `get_form` method:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):

    FooForm = super(FooAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

    class RequestFooForm(FooForm):
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            kwargs['request'] = request
            return FooForm(*args, **kwargs)

    return RequestFooForm
```

Otherwise if you just need access during saving you probably can also have a look at the model admin's `save_form` and `save_model` methods.

Comment: Amazing! Just what I needed. Thanks

Comment: What a neat explanation! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Working for me! I can access the `request` in the Form instance like `self.request`

```py
def get_form(self, request, *args,  **kwargs):
    form = super().get_form(request, *args, **kwargs)
    form.request = request
    return form
```