# get_form_kwargs being omitted

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a simple admin form:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Process
        fields = ["start", "end", "result", "description", "user"]

    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop("user", None)    
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["user"].initial = user
```

The form is being instanciated by a normal ModelAdmin:

```
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SomeForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self, request):
        return {"user": request.user}
    
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, change, **kwargs, **self.get_form_kwargs(request))
        return form
```

The output of the `print` statement is never visible in the terminal. Why? I want to be able to access the "user" as an initial value in the form:

Edit: Code updated according to @Willem Van Onsem's input (still not working: Error: `TypeError` saying `modelform_factory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'`.)

Comment: Your `get_form` seems incomplete in the question?

Comment: True, I copied one line too short :(

Comment: I also tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/54151253/4225972 this approach with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's `ModelAdmin` has no `get_form_kwargs`, yes I know that is strange, since it has a [**`.get_formset_kwargs(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_formset_kwargs). But, well, the `ModelAdmin` is a bit of a misfeature, especially since it is a collection of different views, but it basically violates all patterns the Django views implement. For example it does not make an instance of the view, so `self.request` is not accessible, since that is the `ModelAdmin`, not the view object.

We can do this, but it is *ugly*, no, really. First we update the form to use `self._user` as attribute:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    _user = None

    class Meta:
        model = Process
        fields = ['start', 'end', 'result', 'description', 'user']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].initial = self._user
```

and now we can each time subclass is and inject the user as attribute:

```
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_form(self, reqmuest, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        class SubSomeForm(SomeForm):
            _user = request.user
        return SomeSubForm
```

and that will be the working mechanism.

Comment: I tried this, but got a `TypeError` saying: `modelform_factory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'` - I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @xtlc: i think I found a way, but trust me, it is *ugly*, no really.

Comment: mhm yes that works, thanks a lot for investing braintime! Let's see if some caveats hunt me down later :)

Comment: @xtlc: well I don't guarantee it will work with every extension, action, mixin, etc. Although likely that can be said about any solution: if you override enough functions, eventually evertyhing likely fails. But here I admit I'm not very sure it will work seamlessly with all "infrastructure".

Comment: Thanks nontheless! I wonder if the use case is such a far fetched one, or why this is so complicated to solve "nicely"?

Comment: @xtlc: well, it seems the `ModelAdmin` has no `get_form_kwargs` and `get_form` actually is more a `get_form_class` since it does not return a form *object*, but a form class that is then instantiated. I've seen some tickets regarding modeladmin's, but most are rejected, not because these are bad improvements, but because all sorts of plugins now act on how the admin was constructed. But imho, the admin is not very well designed, probably grew organicaly into some monster, and now they can not fix it anymore.